# In Clickhouse data import, is there a setting to ignore/replace data that is not the correct type for the destination column?

Tags: database, import, clickhouse

I am trying to import data into Clickhouse. 
The thing is that there is a lot of fields filled with data such as "N/A" meanwhile they should be Float.

Is there a setting to say that if the data to insert is not of the correct type for the destination column, Clickhouse should just ignore it or replace it with nan or null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For preprocessing input data can be used the standard Unix utilities like this:

*N/A -> Nan*

```sh
cat data.csv | sed 's/N\/A/NaN/g' | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO table_name FORMAT CSV"
```

*N/A -> NULL*

```sh
cat data.csv | sed 's/N\/A//g' | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO table_name FORMAT CSV"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table XYZ(K Int64, A Float64 default NaN, B Nullable(Float64)) Engine=Memory;
insert into XYZ(K) values(1);
insert into XYZ(K, A, B) values(2, NaN, Null);

SELECT * FROM XYZ

┌─K─┬───A─┬────B─┐
│ 1 │ nan │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 2 │ nan │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
└───┴─────┴──────┘
```

---

```
echo -e "3,N/A,N/A\n4,0.5,0.5"
3,N/A,N/A
4,0.5,0.5

echo -e "3,N/A,N/A\n4,0.5,0.5"|clickhouse-client -q "insert into XYZ SELECT K, ifNull(toFloat64OrNull(A),NaN), toFloat64OrNull(B) FROM input('K Int64, A String, B String') FORMAT CSV";

SELECT * FROM XYZ

┌─K─┬───A─┬────B─┐
│ 3 │ nan │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 4 │ 0.5 │  0.5 │
└───┴─────┴──────┘
```

---

```
create table XYZ_null (K Int64, A String, B String) Engine=Null;
create materialized view XYZ_mv to XYZ as SELECT K, ifNull(toFloat64OrNull(A),NaN) A, toFloat64OrNull(B) B from XYZ_null

echo -e "5,N/A,N/A\n6,0.5,0.5"|clickhouse-client -q "insert into XYZ_null FORMAT CSV";

SELECT * FROM XYZ

┌─K─┬───A─┬────B─┐
│ 5 │ nan │ ᴺᵁᴸᴸ │
│ 6 │ 0.5 │  0.5 │
└───┴─────┴──────┘
```